# Tomcat access to NFS - Can't read new files

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, permissions, liferay, nfs

I mounted a NFS Share from one Machine (Ubuntu14) to my other Machine (also Ubuntu 14) - a webserver running Liferay (portal Framework) on Tomcat (uses Apache with mod_jk)

I can show files, for example Images, from NFS folder to my Website but if i add new files to NFS, i get an 404 Error.

A restart of Tomcat fixes the problem. But i don't want to restart tomcat always when i add new files.

What i've already done:

- The UserID and GroupID of the NFS Share are the same on both machines
- auto_index (Apache) is enabled
- SElinux is disabled

So my questions are:

- What does the restart of Tomcat effect that new files are readable ?
- How can i read my new files without a restart of Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my fault:

It has nothing to do with the NFS !

The problem is that Tomcat does not recognize new files which come into the 

 */webapps/your-webapp/* folder until the 
next deploy of your webapp.

So i mounted my NFS share into another Folder (for example *webapps/images/your-nfs-share/* ).